# Что можно контролировать в windows?

Tags: c++, c

Не давно узнал про wfp и что с его помощью можно взаимодействовать с пакетной обработкой (ну как написано в microsoft). Если я хочу понять как это работает и как можно взаимодействовать с системой. Что надо гуглить? и какие книжки есть?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dn308572.aspx) поюзайте. Там куча всего. Ну и первоисточник, практически. Информации хватит, желания бы столько было.

Comment: @VladSpirin, Хорошо гляну.

Comment: World Food Programme (WFP) - Всемирная продовольственная программа. С чем она там взаимодействует?

Comment: Если имеется в виду WPF, то непонятно при чем там пакетная обработка. Это вроде для как раз наоборот.

Comment: @VTT, Прошу прощения что не уточнил. Имею ввиду windows filtering platform

Comment: @freim, Прошу прощения что не уточнил. Имею ввиду windows filtering platform

Comment: Ну тогда прямая дорога на [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FWP/windows-filtering-platform-start-page)

Comment: @VTT, Да я уже понял. Но хотел бы просто, уточнить что работает с самой системой как WFP. То там очень много всего.

Comment: Это хорошо нарисовано на странице [архитектуры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FWP/windows-filtering-platform-architecture-overview)